# div width:100% will over the browser window border

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

here is my code:

```
<body style="width:100%; height:100%; margin:0px">
<div id="horizontal-bar" style="width:100%; height:34px; border: 10px solid;"></div>
```

here is my screenshot:
[image]

the #horizontal-bar right border doesn't show, how to make #horizontal-bar completely show in browser window, if css cannot do it? can i do it in js?

Answer (score 8):

Here, you need to use the `box-sizing: border-box` because, `border` is also a part of the box model:

[image]
<sub>(source: [codemancers.com](http://crypt.codemancers.com/assets/images/boxmodel/compare_models-ec8c849825b4fb3e1e6177e49e15d800cb77bdeaa99e6adcf896a65af62ab99f.png))</sub>

**Snippet**

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}
#horizontal-bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 34px;
  border: 10px solid;
  /* Add This */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="horizontal-bar"></div>
```

Your old, non-working code for comparison is:

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}
#horizontal-bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 34px;
  border: 10px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="horizontal-bar"></div>
```

Comment: This is a nice visual answer. I would also add this from w3schools: "The width property does not include padding, borders, or margins; it sets the width of the area inside the padding, border, and margin of the element!".

Comment: @JohnH Yea, but ... :)

Answer (score -2):

use this code :

`<script type="text/javascript">
    var w = $(window).width();
    $('.horizontal-bar').css('width', w);
</script>
<body style="width:100%; height:100%;margin:0px">
<div id="horizontal-bar" style="height:34px; border: 10px solid;"></div>`

Comment: **1.** What does this code do? **2.** Why JavaScript? Do you know what's the problem happening here? **3.** Did you see my answer before answering?

Comment: You don't need JavaScript for this. That's what I am trying to tell. Did you see my answer?